# Collapsing Toolbar layout with logo, title, subtitle in toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

[image: First Image]
[image: Second image]
[image: Third image]

I want do this but with Collapsing toolbar layout or display the logo and title in toolbar after scroll.

```
    <!-- Toolbars -->
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/background_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/background_1"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/avatar_image"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/circular_image_avatar"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/circular_image_avatar"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_placerholder"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:transitionName="image_toolbar"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name title"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/item_padding_top_bottom"
                android:gravity="center"
                style="@style/titleText_toolbar"
                android:layout_below="@+id/avatar_image"
                android:transitionName="title_toolbar"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Subtitle"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                style="@style/captionText_toolbar"
                android:layout_below="@+id/profile_title" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <!-- avatar image and title, subtitle -->

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Please help me

Comment: What code have you tried? What problems are you running into? Describe it more and we will (probably) help.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Yj7pe5Y.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/AUVokgc.jpg
http://i.imgur.com/dqWq3Fp.jpg


Sorry I don't have 10 reputation for post images :(

Comment: The code is irrelevant in this case, I want know how to do it

Comment: hi @tonilopezmr could you post how you achieved this?

Comment: @HardikAmal check out this https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have preperead two amaizing avatar collapsing demo samples with approach that doesn’t use a custom `CoordinatorLayoutBehavior`!

To view my samples native code: [*"Collapsing Avatar Toolbar Sample"*](https://github.com/SergeyBurlaka/CollapsingAvatarToolbarSample)

To read my  [*"Animation Collapsing Toolbar Android"*](https://medium.com/@anatoliy8827/how-to-animate-collapsing-avatar-toolbar-sample-f3f37ab6c35e) post on Medium.

---

**demo 1**[image]   **demo 2** [image]

---

Instead of use use a custom `CoordinatorLayoutBehavior` i use an `OnOffsetChangedListener` which comes from `AppBarLayout`.

```
private lateinit var appBarLayout: AppBarLayout

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo_1)
        ...
        appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout)

        /**/
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(
                AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener { appBarLayout, i ->
                   ...
                    /**/
                    updateViews(Math.abs(i / appBarLayout.totalScrollRange.toFloat()))
                })
    }
```

### Demo 1

[image]

---

in `updateViews` method avatar changes the size and changes avatar’s X, Y position translation in first demo.

```
private fun updateViews(offset: Float) {

        ...

        /* Collapse avatar img*/
        ivUserAvatar.apply {
            when {
                offset > avatarAnimateStartPointY -> {
                    val avatarCollapseAnimateOffset = (offset - avatarAnimateStartPointY) * avatarCollapseAnimationChangeWeight
                    val avatarSize = EXPAND_AVATAR_SIZE - (EXPAND_AVATAR_SIZE - COLLAPSE_IMAGE_SIZE) * avatarCollapseAnimateOffset
                    this.layoutParams.also {
                        it.height = Math.round(avatarSize)
                        it.width = Math.round(avatarSize)
                    }
                    invisibleTextViewWorkAround.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, offset)

                    this.translationX = ((appBarLayout.width - horizontalToolbarAvatarMargin - avatarSize) / 2) * avatarCollapseAnimateOffset
                    this.translationY = ((toolbar.height  - verticalToolbarAvatarMargin - avatarSize ) / 2) * avatarCollapseAnimateOffset
                }
                else -> this.layoutParams.also {
                    if (it.height != EXPAND_AVATAR_SIZE.toInt()) {
                        it.height = EXPAND_AVATAR_SIZE.toInt()
                        it.width = EXPAND_AVATAR_SIZE.toInt()
                        this.layoutParams = it
                    }
                    translationX = 0f
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

to find `avatarAnimateStartPointY` and `avatarCollapseAnimationChangeWeight` (for convert general offset to avatar animate offset):

```
private var avatarAnimateStartPointY: Float = 0F
 private var avatarCollapseAnimationChangeWeight: Float = 0F
 private var isCalculated = false
 private var verticalToolbarAvatarMargin =0F
...
if (isCalculated.not()) {
    avatarAnimateStartPointY = 
                 Math.abs((appBarLayout.height - (EXPAND_AVATAR_SIZE + horizontalToolbarAvatarMargin)) / appBarLayout.totalScrollRange)

    avatarCollapseAnimationChangeWeight = 1 / (1 - avatarAnimateStartPointY)

    verticalToolbarAvatarMargin = (toolbar.height - COLLAPSE_IMAGE_SIZE) * 2
    isCalculated = true
 }
```

### Demo 2

[image]

---

avatar change his size and than animate move to right at one moment with top toolbar text became to show and moving to left.

You need to track states: `TO_EXPANDED_STATE` changing, `TO_COLLAPSED_STATE` changing,  `WAIT_FOR_SWITCH`.

```
 /*Collapsed/expended sizes for views*/
            val result: Pair<Int, Int> = when {
                percentOffset < ABROAD -> {
                    Pair(TO_EXPANDED_STATE, cashCollapseState?.second ?: WAIT_FOR_SWITCH)
                }
                else -> {
                    Pair(TO_COLLAPSED_STATE, cashCollapseState?.second ?: WAIT_FOR_SWITCH)
                }
            }
```

Create animation for avatar on state switch change:

```
   result.apply {
        var translationY = 0f
        var headContainerHeight = 0f
        val translationX: Float
        var currentImageSize = 0
        when {
            cashCollapseState != null && cashCollapseState != this -> {
                when (first) {
                    TO_EXPANDED_STATE -> {
                        translationY = toolbar.height.toFloat()
                        headContainerHeight = appBarLayout.totalScrollRange.toFloat()
                        currentImageSize = EXPAND_AVATAR_SIZE.toInt()
                        /**/
                        titleToolbarText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        titleToolbarTextSingle.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                        background.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this@Demo2Activity, R.color.color_transparent))
                        /**/
                        ivAvatar.translationX = 0f
                    }

                    TO_COLLAPSED_STATE -> {
                        background.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this@Demo2Activity, R.color.colorPrimary))
                        currentImageSize = COLLAPSE_IMAGE_SIZE.toInt()
                        translationY = appBarLayout.totalScrollRange.toFloat() - (toolbar.height - COLLAPSE_IMAGE_SIZE) / 2
                        headContainerHeight = toolbar.height.toFloat()
                        translationX = appBarLayout.width / 2f - COLLAPSE_IMAGE_SIZE / 2 - margin * 2
                        /**/
                        ValueAnimator.ofFloat(ivAvatar.translationX, translationX).apply {
                            addUpdateListener {
                                if (cashCollapseState!!.first == TO_COLLAPSED_STATE) {
                                    ivAvatar.translationX = it.animatedValue as Float
                                }
                            }
                            interpolator = AnticipateOvershootInterpolator()
                            startDelay = 69
                            duration = 350
                            start()
                        }
                       ...
                    }
                }

                ivAvatar.apply {
                    layoutParams.height = currentImageSize
                    layoutParams.width = currentImageSize
                }
                collapsingAvatarContainer.apply {
                    layoutParams.height = headContainerHeight.toInt()
                    this.translationY = translationY
                    requestLayout()
                }
                /**/
                cashCollapseState = Pair(first, SWITCHED)
            }
```

---

To view my samples native code: [*"Collapsing Avatar Toolbar Sample"*](https://github.com/SergeyBurlaka/CollapsingAvatarToolbarSample)

Comment: @Serg, can you make your sample in java?

Comment: I need this in java as well.

Comment: Very useful solution, even in 2020.

Answer (score 2):

I think these type of animations can be achieved easily using MotionLayout. I have implemented sample collapsing layout using MotionLayout [here](https://medium.com/@jossypaul/motionlayout-simplest-way-to-create-beautiful-animations-in-android-9935db529e75). You can modify it for your use case. Simple change the start and end constraints.